# TypeError: (0 , _reduxjs_toolkit__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.createAsyncThunk) is not a function

Tags: redux, next.js, toolkit, thunk

Suddenly had this error after (it seems..) trying to deploy my client to Vercel.

I'm using NextJS and I'm fetching data server side with getStaticProps.

Tried reinstalling toolkit but the problem persist.

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
```

What could possibly be wrong ?

if it matters, here's how I use createAsyncThunk in my slice :

```
    export const countProducts = createAsyncThunk(
    "products/countProducts",
    async (undefined, { getState }) => {
    const { filterBy } = getState().product;
    const url = `${process.env.STRAPI_URL}/products/count?categories.name_contains=${filterBy}`;
    const { data } = await api.get(url);
    return data;
  }
);
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it, I just somehow had an older version of toolkit installed (v1.2.x).